# How to attach events to dynamically loaded subpages in jQueryMobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've the following code that uses jQueryMobile Sliders:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() {
                var row = $(
                     '<div data-role="fieldcontain">' +                  
                             '<label for="slider"></label>' +
                             '<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="99"/>' +
                     '</div>');
                $('#lights_content').append(row);
                $(row).find('#slider').bind('change', function(){ console.log($(this).val()); });
             });
        </script>
</head>
<body> 
        <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="b">
                <div data-role="content">
                        <a href="#lights" data-transition="slide">Lights</a>
                </div> 
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="lights" data-theme="b" data-add-back-btn="true">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"><h4>Light</h4></div> 
                <div data-role="content" id="lights_content"></div> 
        </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

The *change* event do not fire while slider is moving. I've found that the problem is because jQueryMobile renders the page on first navigation to my subpage Lights and destroys the event itself. This can be proven using

```
console.log($('#slider').data('events').change);
```

in JS console just after attachement of the event and after the rendering of the page. The question is:

**How to attach persistent event handler or instruct jQueryMobile to attach it in future**

I don't want to add the event after page rendering. I want to dynamically create the element ant attach the event immediately (or attach a callback that will attach the event after rendering).

**UPD**: Here is a link to [JavaScript kitchen](http://jsfiddle.net/t7AFe/), where you can see how it is not working.

Comment: Im slightly confused, are you creating multiple sliders? If so, why do you have the same id for all the sliders? You shouldn't need to use find either, a simple selector should work just fine.

Comment: This is part of the code, so, don't be confused by stranges. Indeed I'm using same id for all sliders, but I do $(el).find('#slider') to select the child slider under some el. This is not good, I know...

Comment: You should change it to a class instead of id. It's not proper html as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (I just tested it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtwebb/EybMk/)). Change:

```
$(row).find('#slider').bind('change', function(){$('#vv').val($(this).val()); });
```

to:

```
$('div').delegate('#slider','change', function(){$('#vv').text($(this).val()); });
```

And if you wanted to make sure that it changes just the next `span` you could do something like this:

```
$('div').delegate('#slider','change', function(){
   $(this).closest('#lights_content').next('span').text($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: Not at all. Instead of `on` try `live`. See if that helps.

Comment: here is a link to my demo: jsfiddle.net/t7AFe/. You can try it and figure out the problem

Comment: don't use live, use delegate instead.

Comment: @matt - I just tried using `delegate` with his code and it didn't work. `live` works just fine though.

Comment: @john live has been deprecated a long time ago for good reason. Especially since this is will be mobile, it's probably a better idea to use delegate. Delegate is exactly like .on(), except syntax is slighty reversed. `$('body').delegate('#slider', 'click', function(){});` this is how you would use it. Although, it still disregards the fact that there are multiple elements on the page with the same id, that's a big no-no and it could give him problems.

Comment: @john also i realize they have examples of .live() on jquery mobile, honestly i don't understand why, I'm not sure if that page is just old, but it shouldn't be used anymore unless jquery mobile has it's own .live function.

Comment: With `live` it works in the demo, but not in production code. Will dig more. Another solution I found is to run `row.trigger('create')` before adding event with `bind`. But again on production it does not work - it seems that all elements are rerendered somewhere and my event handlers are deleted.

Comment: @matt - I had the syntax wrong when I tried `delegate()`. It does work. Is there a reason that `body` should be used instead of `div` since his selector is a div? Also, I agree that he shouldn't be using id's if he's going to have more than one of these on a page. I just wasn't sure how it was going to be set up, so didn't know if this was going to be the only one on the page.

Comment: @poltos - Are you getting any errors in your your console? Or, if you have multiple sliders on a page, it could be that the id's are causing problems as matt suggested.

Comment: @john delegate works differently than live. Live you specified just one thing, so it bubbles up the entire DOM. Delegate is different in that you only go so far, so you want to get close to the element and delegate should be faster. Body is ok to use most of the time (when unsure just use body), since this is where your content should start anyway. But in his case he could probably use #lights_content instead of body. You are looking in a container i guess you can say, so you want something pretty specific like a div with an id. It's faster to find a node with an id, than with a class.

Comment: @matt - Ahhh. Thanks! I guess you learn something new every day :)

Comment: Dear @jhon. After all tests the trick with `delegate` works perfectly in my case! With live this was not the case. Thank you!

And the `delegate` is new for me too. Will read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you should be calling pageInit instead of $(document).ready?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: So, should I use $(document).bind('pageinit', ...)? The problem is that after my SLIDER is rendered by jQueryMobile, events are deleted.